# Reporting on completed sprint

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-reports

Want to build a report showing each team member's percentage contribution per a completed Sprint. 
We break up the work in Tasks and assign a Remaining Work value to indicate the time needed. The problem then is that remaining value is clear or decreased as the sprint progresses.

Have been looking for a way to find the original remaining value, so I can use it for reporting post the sprint. All in an effort to try and build a relation between originally set Effort and Actual hours.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I have to say this, as a Professional Scrum Trainer with Scrum.org, we highly discourage the breakdown of effort to the individual team member as part of standard reporting. Where scrum is concerned, the individual contribution is of little consequence outside of the team context, and inside of the team we feel that team members should be able to openly discuss the perceived value added by other team members as part of their Sprint Retrospective.

Secondly, because TFS can't register multiple users being assigned to a task, nor support the trackign of hours spent by multiple team members on the same task, your report will either be incomplete at best, cause additional administration overhead in most cases and may even cause team members to not work together at worst.

That said...

TFS tracks all assigned and saved values for work item fields. Using the API it's easy to iterate through the work items and retrieve their previous Revisions. As an alternative, the API offers `asof` work item queries which allow you to track what the values of a workitem were on a specific date. This information is also store in the TFS datawarehouse, if you are using it, aggregated at the daily level.

But if you need accurate tracking of time spent, the only reliable way is to add the Completed Work field to your work item type definition:

> **Completed Work**
>
> The amount of work that has been spent implementing a task. You can specify work in hours or in days. There are no inherent time units associated with this field.
>
> Reference name=Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork, Data type=Double
>
> Task, Bug

This is required to cover cases where the original estimate was lower than the actual time spent, remaining work would in that case remain the same, or even increase, while a team member had spent time on that item. without also tracking CompletedWork, this data is lost.

The Agile and CMMI template use this field by default. The Scrum template doesn't, you can guess why based on my initial cautions.

Comment: Thanks, @jessehouwing and I fully agree with you the breakdown of effort to the individual team member should not be done in Scrum process.