# Getting hours worked during a sprint in Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm over a team of developers whose primary responsibility is the sustainment of our production applications.  Once a month we work on a support sprint for an app, fixing any reported bugs and adding new enhancements to that application.  My leadership has asked for a reporting of the hours worked by each developer during the sprint, which I know I can get from looking at each task, but is there a way to generate some kind of report from Team Services that would have that information in it?

Comment: Hi David, any update on this?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, I ended up using the Analytic Views in VSTS (now Azure DevOps) and built my own power bi report.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in report can be generated to get what you want. Since TFS/VSTS is an effort tracking system and not a time tracking system it is a loosing battle to try and track billable time as part of TFS/VSTS.

Agile projects don't focus on how long individual tasks take -- they focus on how much value the development team is providing over the course of a set period of time. One thing might be estimated low, one task might be estimated high, but it ultimately doesn't matter as long as the team delivers what they committed to deliver.

About Scrum, suggest you take a look at this related question: [Reporting on completed sprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800097/reporting-on-completed-sprint)

If you insist on achieving this, you could use some 3-rd party extension such as [Imaginet Time Sheet](http://www.imaginet.com/imaginet-timesheet-for-tfs/) & [Timetracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Berichthaus.TfsTimetracker).  For example, about time tracker, it is fully integrated into TFS, which allows tracking directly against workitems and offers data export as well as automatic filling of the fields mentioned above. With the help of the extension, project manager could have all times based on rules automatically reported back into MS Project.

Answer (score -1):

The work item experience in VSTS isn't intended to be a time tracking mechanism, it's intended to be a tool for teams to manage work in an Agile fashion. Agile isn't about hours worked, it's about delivering value and meeting commitments.

You'll need to evaluate a third-party extension, such as [TimeTracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Berichthaus.TfsTimetracker). I have no experience with it, so I can't vouch for how good it is (or isn't!).