# How can I query work items (User Stories) that added into Sprint after Sprint Planning?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, how can I drill down and get a list of which work items are added as total scope increase using queries or any other method?

Comment: Hi rick, If have any misunderstanding, could you please re-describe more details about scenario? I will still be here to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vito, I am interested to query which user stories are added after first day of sprint? I dont think created date field can query what was added into sprint after sprint planning (first day of sprint).

Comment: The closest thing I can get is to click on the blue area with the day with total scope changes in burndown chart with column options of iteration path to really see which user stories has move to another sprint.

Comment: Hi @rick, someone change the User Stories Iteration path to add these to the new Sprint, or create new User Stories in this Sprint. And now, you want to query it and list these work item, is it right?

Comment: yes that is correct. either they create new user stories or take any user stories from the product backlog into this current sprint's iteration path (after first day of current sprint).

Comment: Hi @rick, I have tried it but cannot list the work items. As a workaround, we can query the Sprint work items, then check the work item history. Here is an [sample code](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx) to check the all history. We should change the TFS API to Azure DevOps API.

Comment: looks like it's a limitation in this case. hopefully in future we can get that info out-of-box from ADO.

Comment: You can feel free to raise a suggestion ticket, the azure devops product team will check it and reply you. Thanks

Comment: nope, nothing much other than the manual method. I have suggested a feature in User Voice site [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1189119/have-a-list-on-work-item-that-was-assigned-removed.html)

Comment: Hi @rick, Thanks for your sharing, I have vote this ticket and share the link in the answer, the Azure DevOps product team will check the User Voice and reply you.

Comment: @VitoLiu the referenced sample code is now a dead link. Here's the wayback machine capture that can be of use: http://web.archive.org/web/20210125081328/http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same challenge. I have been able to generate a list of non-completed work items that were added during the sprint using the following method. It doesn't take into account those items that were added after sprint start AND finished in the sprint, as it is based on remaining work only:

1. Click Analytics in Sprint board
2. Backlog/Work items set to "Backlog items backlog"
3. Burndown on set to "Count of Work Items"
4. Click the right most dot in the chart for remaining work (you can disable overlapping curves by clicking the legends)

[image]

5. This leads you to a query containing all the work item ids. Copy that string.
6. Do the same for the beginning of the sprint, left most blue dot. Copy that string as well.
7. Create a new query with the string from 5 and 6 respectively, like this
   [image]

/Chris L.

Comment: Hey Chris, yea this seems to be the only manual way to get the list, but if we have a lot of projects to find out, this will not be scalable approach. Thanks for showing the detailed steps over here for better reference. Please upvote the suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1189119/have-a-list-on-work-item-that-was-assigned-removed.html)  I raised in MS Developer Community.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#get-list-of-work-items,-all-expanded) from Azure DevOps Services REST API 5.1

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=297,299,300&fields=System.Id,System.Title,System.WorkItemType,Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork&api-version=5.1
```

What it does is to send the GET Request with User Story Id and the timestamp you want to fetch. Then you will get JSON response on that time you want to get.

And result is:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 297,
      "rev": 1,
      "fields": {
        "System.Id": 297,
        "System.WorkItemType": "Product Backlog Item",
        "System.Title": "Customer can sign in using their Microsoft Account"
      },
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/297"
    },
    {
      "id": 299,
      "rev": 7,
      "fields": {
        "System.Id": 299,
        "System.WorkItemType": "Task",
        "System.Title": "JavaScript implementation for Microsoft Account",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork": 4
      },
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/299"
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "rev": 1,
      "fields": {
        "System.Id": 300,
        "System.WorkItemType": "Task",
        "System.Title": "Unit Testing for MSA login",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork": 3
      },
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/300"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just adding: the parameter &errorPolicy:omit may be useful. [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#uri-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all newly added work items, we can use the field Created Date to get the result.

In addition, the Sprint page list the work items via iteration path instead of date.

[image]

**Update1**

We cannot list these work item in the azure devops now. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

**Update2**

We can vote and follow this [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1189119/have-a-list-on-work-item-that-was-assigned-removed.html) to get the latest news.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been looking into an answer for this, and for those who are in the same ship;
I have found Scope Change documentation on Microsoft's Azure DevOps GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/boards/sprints/scrum-overview.md#query-sprint-scope-changes

*Note: File has formatting issues but bear with me.
Broken images can be found in this folder, if needed:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/tree/main/docs/boards/sprints/media/overview*

Suggested solution is a little bit hacky, but it should work.

What you need to do is simply is:

1. Go to your velocity chart (in team's dashboard)
2. Click on the bar which stands for 'Planned'
3. Click on 'Editor' on the Custom Query screen listing work items
4. Add Iteration Path clause to the query with its respective value
5. Add Area Path clause to the query with its respective value
6. Change filter operator from 'IN' to 'NOT IN' for ID field
7. Add Created Date as a column option, and sort by that field. You can then view the existing work items that were added to the sprint and what newly created work items were added.

Congratulations, you have filtered the items added to the sprint after spring start date.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I've found to determine what was ADDED to a Sprint after it began is to use the Velocity Widget available on Dashboards.

The Velocity Widget displays the Planned, Completed and Incomplete items for each Sprint.

[Velocity Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1zbZ.png)

If you click the column displaying the Planned items for the Sprint you are directed to a Custom Query whose results is a list of the items which were in the Sprint when it began. If you switch to the Editor view of the Query you will a list of all the IDs of the work items which were part of the sprint when it began:

[Custom Query - Sprint's original scope items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnvkB.png)

You can use this list of PLANNED items for the Sprint to determine any items which were ADDED to the Sprint:

[New Query - items OTHER than original scope items in Sprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F1KU.png)